# vagrant puppet modulepath

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, puppet, vagrant

```
Puppet 2.7.19
Vagrant version 1.0.6
VM OS Ubuntu 12.04
```

I am attempting to set the puppet module path from vagrant. Which seems like it should be very simple.

In my Vagrant file I have:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "my_modules"
  config.vm.provision :puppet, :options => ["--modulepath", "my_modules"]
end
```

When I change the the value of the modulepath it seems to have no effect (after `vagrant reload`)

Here is a snipplet from `vagrant up`

```
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- manifests: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] -- v-pp-m0: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
```

Notice the `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0` ? What is this about?

Then from inside vagrant:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ puppet apply --configprint modulepath
/home/vagrant/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

So when I do: `puppet module install puppetlabs/mysql`

I get this error:

```
Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
Error: Could not install module 'puppetlabs-mysql' (latest)
  Directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules does not exist
```

So I have to:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/.puppet$ mkdir /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
vagrant@precise64:~/.puppet$ puppet module install puppetlabs/mysql
Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
Downloading from http://forge.puppetlabs.com ...
Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
└─┬ puppetlabs-mysql (v0.6.1)
  └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v3.2.0)
```

And then I have to move the modules into place where vagrant can see them...

```
mv /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules/mysql /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
```

Seems like maybe this is a bug or I am really missing something. Seems pretty basic so I would like to hear how others solved this.

Thanks!

Comment: Vagrant assumes that it should link your modules via VirtualBox shared folder into the VM so the modules exist on the host. Using the Vagrant provisioner for modules stored inside the VM may exploit what vagrant provisioners are built for...

Comment: Vagrant does link a modules directory inside a shared folder on the vm. It appears to be in `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0` I am trying to have vagrant set the puppet `modulepath` so they match up.

Comment: So you want to set the location on the host where your puppet modules are located?

Comment: It should be done like this `config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "my_modules"`, see [here](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/puppet.html)

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, or set puppet's module path to look in `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0`. My apologies if my question was not clear about this.

Comment: `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0` is the folder inside the VM where the modules are "blended" in, puppet is launched by Vagrant accordingly

Comment: Yes, I do have `config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "my_modules"` in my config. I did not post this in my original question. All that seems to do is tell <name>.pp files where the modules are located when `vagrant provision` occurs. It does not actually do anything as far as setting the `modulepath`

Comment: I suppose Vagrant sets the modulepath only for the puppet run it launches itself but not in a persistent manner on the guest..

Comment: Perhaps it does... Seems like there should be an option to set this. That is what I thought `config.vm.provision :puppet, :options => ["--modulepath", "my_modules"]` would do.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or are you just curious how it works? Seems like manually installing puppet modules inside the automatically configured guest is not the way Vagrant works - you should add this module on the host..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26490/discussion-between-michael-irey-and-cmur2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're effectively specifying module_path twice:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "my_modules"
  config.vm.provision :puppet, :options => ["--modulepath", "my_modules"]
end
```

I'm not sure which would wind up overriding the other, but you shouldn't be specifying the module path in both ways.

I think it's better to use vagrant's support for module_path in preference to the `:options` array, as in your first line.  I like the following style better still:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.module_path = ["modules-contrib","modules-custom"]
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end # puppet
end # config
```

You asked about `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0`.  That's the first item in the modulepath array, where the `0` is the array index.  Ie in my example above, the `modules-contrib` and `modules-custom` directories from my vagrant project get mounted at `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0` and `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-1` respectively.

You shouldn't be installing puppet modules within the vagrant box.  Instead, install them in a modules directory in your vagrant project in the host environment.

Rather than installing them one by one, I'd recommend using librarian puppet (`gem install librarian-puppet`), and putting a `Puppetfile` in your vagrant project, which lists all the third party modules you want, and tells librarian-puppet to put them in a separate modules directory from the one you use for your custom puppet modules.  I use the `modules-contrib` directory for third party modules, and put my own in `modules-custom`.

Tell the librarian where to put its modules:

```
librarian-puppet config --local path modules-contrib
```

See https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet for the layout of the Puppetfile.  It's pretty simple, and lets you mix up puppet-forge and git sources as you like.

You should add the `modules-contrib` folder to your `.gitignore` file (assuming you use git), and rely on version control of the `Puppetfile` file.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. When I get a chance to test it out and this works for me, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

As it reads from [Vagrant Documentation](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/puppet.html):

> The Vagrant Puppet provisioner allows you to mount a local folder of
>   modules onto the VM, and will configure Puppet to be aware of them,
>   automatically.

The **local folder** refers to a folder on your host machine.

And then:

> The module path is expanded relative to the folder containing the
>   Vagrantfile.

The folder containing your VagrantFile is on your host machine.

So, you're trying to use an option that sets a path to a folder on the host machine to control the path to a folder on the VM.

You have to put your modules on the host machine, not on the VM. Here's an example:

**HOST MACHINE**

~/Dev/mybox/            -> base path of the "mybox" Vagrant VM

~/Dev/mybox/VagrantFile -> Vagrant file that controls "mybox"

~/Dev/mybox/puppet/modules    -> path to the puppet modules used on "mybox"

~/Dev/mybox/puppet/modules/apache -> path of the apache module to be applied on "mybox"

VagrantFile:

```
  # Enable puppet provisioning
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
     puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
     puppet.manifests_path = "puppet"
     puppet.manifest_file  = "mybox.pp"
  end
```

**VIRTUAL MACHINE**

When I start mybox:

```
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- manifests: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] -- v-pp-m0: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
```

then

```
vagrant@mybox:~$ cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
vagrant@mybox:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0$ ls
apache
```

As you can see the ~/Dev/mybox/puppet/modules/apache directory on the host machine was mounted  on /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0 on the Vagrant VM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

so, if you're like me and have been staring at this question and the answer, wondering what was different in your case, here's what I have been missing:

From the vagrant docs on provisioning I had picked up this snippet:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "my_manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
end
```

while trying to get a module to be recognized in the guest, I picked up this line (probably from [here](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/puppet.html)):

```
config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "my_modules"
```

not knowing ruby or vagrant very well, I put it right under the first snippet, assuming it would somehow add to it. That did not work.

What **does** work, however, is this:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "my_manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  puppet.module_path = "my_modules"
end
```

Sometimes the simple solutions are the hardest to find.

[EDIT]

It also helps to understand that executing the "puppet apply --configprint modulepath" command on the guest VM won't show you the modulepath that puppet will use when it's invoked by Vagrant.